# Insert json object in database automatically?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

I have a very large json object that I want to insert in a nosql database, automatically. I would like to know:

- how can I create the database schema from that json object?
- how to insert it in the database?

I am using Node.js and MongoDB. I retrieve the object with an http request and I want to store it in MongoDB, to work with it later

Answer (score -1):

There are many informations missing. NoSQL database can mean a lot. Which database do you mean ? Graph database, Key->Value database, Document database ? Also there is a lack of standardization among NoSQL databases, therefore this would be DB-depedent.

For Example, in MongoDB, you would not create any schema. Just create a collection and insert your objects. That's it.

Therefore, this depends on:

- Database used (MongoDB, Couchbase, other ..)
- Programming language & environment used. Do you connect to the database from a program written in Java ? From Python ? Other language ?

Anyway, [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) can do what you ask for you with it's document database.

Comment: I am using Node.js and MongoDB. I retrieve the object with an http request and I want to store it in MongoDB, to work with it later.

Comment: The answer is more of a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Yes, becasue Stack Overflow does not allow me to comment and nobody wanted to reply.

Comment: @john You can store it in a MongoDB collection directly then. :)